# How can I set the cell in a jqGrid if the name in colmodel is an integer?

Tags: jqgrid

jqgrid setcell causes issues when the name in colmodel is an integer. It gives error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatter' of undefined.

My sequence of adding `grid.locale-en.js` and `jqgrid-min.js` is Right.

To be Precise the error is in the line :

```
var h = a.p.colModel[e]; if (h.formatter !== void 0)
```

in `jqgrid-min.js` where e the colmodel name (note this is an integer).

This is the way I am setting cell.

```
$("#GoingCostLogGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, Costs_ProjectOrProgram , cellValue_CurrentTotalforAllFY);
```

Where Costs_ProjectOrProgram is an integer also the column name in colmodel.

Comment: **What version of jqGrid you use?** You should include the line number of **non-minimized** file (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.js` depend on which version you use). What you mean "the name in colmodel is an integer"? Which exactly value you use? (`0` or `123` or ...). The name is always **string**. So you should use at least `"0"` or `"123"` instead of `0` or `123`. Why you use so strange names of the columns at all? Why you not change the names to `"c1"`, `"c2"`, `"c3"`, ... instead of ``"1"``, ``"2"``, ``"3"``, ...?

Comment: I have been using jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid (jquery.jqGrid.src.js) the exact line number is 1121 [  if(cm.formatter !== undefined)  ].

Comment: It means that you call [formatter](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.js#L1119) function with the wrong `colpos` parameter. I asked you **multiple questions**, but you answer on the first one only.

Comment: I have been using jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid (jquery.jqGrid.src.js) the exact line number is 1121 [  if(cm.formatter !== undefined)  ]. Also  name attribute in colmodel is an integer like "51" OR "52" With double quotes. The reason behind giving integer as name attribute is I have been using quickbase where it is the field ID of the data from database.I have been getting data separately using quickbase api and the integrating using datatype local to be specific data is of format var data = {["51" : "USA", "52" : "BID done" ,"53" : "Paid"]}

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? If you use `datatype: "json"` then you can use `jsonmap` property of `colModel`. It specify the value of input property. By the way the `var data = {["51" : "USA", "52" : "BID done" ,"53" : "Paid"]}` have syntax error. You mean probably ` var data = [{"51" : "USA", "52" : "BID done" ,"53" : "Paid"}]`. I don't recommend you to use numbers as the value of `name` property in `colModel`. You could have only additional problems from there. One can easy use `name` values which corresponds `id` rules of CSS. The exact implementation (like `jsonmap`) depends on details.

Comment: jqGrid allows **many way of usage**. You should always post more details which shows **how you use it**. For example you can use `datatype: "xml"` or `datatype: "json"` without `loadonce: true` and so don't have any local data in jqGrid. You can use Virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`), TreeGrid, Grouping, Pivot Grid, Subgrids and so on. If you use cell editing or form editing then you have absolutely another possibilities compared with inline editing. I can continue... You should understand that if you want that somebody helps you then you should include **more details** about your implementation.

Comment: I am using datatype: "local" . And yes data format is  var data = [{"51" : "USA", "52" : "BID done" ,"53" : "Paid"}] . I have to use it as integer not sure exactly why its should be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **large difference** if you call `setCell` with number (like `12`) as parameter or with the string which contains the number (like `"12"`). The number parameter will be interpreted as the **index** in `colModel` array, but the string value will be interpreted as **column name**.

So if the type of `Costs_ProjectOrProgram` is number and you want to interpret it as string then you should convert the variable to the string. So you should use

```js
$("#GoingCostLogGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, String(Costs_ProjectOrProgram),
    cellValue_CurrentTotalforAllFY);
```

instead of

```js
$("#GoingCostLogGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, Costs_ProjectOrProgram,
    cellValue_CurrentTotalforAllFY);
```

By the way, it's very bad to use variables with the first capital character. Corresponds to the name conversion of JavaScript one should use such names **only for constructors** (constructors of the class). It makes easy to see how to use the identifier. For example you need use `var d = new Date(2015, 3, 24);` and not `var d = Date(2015, 3, 24);` even if you could have the same results in many web browsers in the case of the above usage of `Date`. You can see, that even the formatter of JavaScript code displays the identify, which have the first capital character, in another color to stress that it have *another meaning* as the standard variable (`cellValue_CurrentTotalforAllFY` for example). I strictly recommend you to hold the name conversion existing in the language which you use.

**UPDATED**: jqGrid do the following: at the beginning of the code of `setCell` it try to convert column name parameter to number using `isNaN(colname)`. If the column name is number or string which contains the number then it will be interpreted **as the index of the column** (see [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.js#L3634-L3640)). So to solve the problem you have to use `setCell`, `getCell`, `getCol` and many other methods with the index of the column instead of the name. So you have to do the following

```js
var colModel = $("#GoingCostLogGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
    iCol, nCol = colModel.length; 

for (iCol = 0; iCol < nCol; iCol++) {
    if (colModel[iCol].name === Costs_ProjectOrProgram) {
        $("#GoingCostLogGrid").jqGrid("setCell", rowId, iCol,
            cellValue_CurrentTotalforAllFY);
    }
}
```

If you have many places which need to do the same then you can place the searching of column index by the column name in the function and to call if when it's required.

If you would use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead of jqGrid 4.6 then you can use `jsonmap` even in case of usage `datatype: "local"`. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/The-usage-of-jsonmap-with-local-data) for more details. In the way you can define the column as `{name: "c5", jsonmap: "5"}` instead of usage  `{name: "5"}` and to have the described above problems. Alternatively you can change the input data so that the properties of input data will starts with a letter.

Comment: Yes I have have maintained the name conversion . It just to show here I have shortened it a bit Whole name is var = tblFundingDeclaredTableCost_ProjectProgram. I have tried the solution you mention but still same error persist.

Comment: @ZohebKadiwal: You should understand that should include more details about your implementation if you want that somebody helps you to solve your problem. You should **be exact** `var = tblFundingDeclaredTableCost_ProjectProgram` for example have wrong syntax. If you have error in the call of `setCell` then you should include **exact values of parameters which you use** and include all references. For example `tblFundingDeclaredTableCost_ProjectProgram` is equal to `"12"` and you can column in `colModel` with defined as `{name: `"12"`, ... }`...

Comment: @ZohebKadiwal: I posted **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @ZohebKadiwal: You are welcome! I recommend you to post the demo which reproduces the problem. You can create it in JSFiddle for example. The demo should use non-minimized jqGrid version. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/o6g9rnug/ as an example. You can modify an existing jsfiddle.net, save it and post the url. One can debug the code having the demo which reproduce the problem. So one can find the solution of the problem *very quickly*. It will saves your time and the time of the person who answer on your question.